# Imports in files inside module give ImportError in python2 & works fine for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, python-2.x

If I have some file 'needy' in my module 'module', which is trying to access 'utils' in the same 'module'. Inside 'needy':

```
from module.utils import fly    # Works in python3
```

whereas

```
from utils import fly           # Works in python2
```

Example

```
python/pulla git:(master) ✗ ± pulla
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pulla", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Pulla==0.0.5', 'console_scripts', 'pulla')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pulla/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pulla.pulla import Pulla
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pulla/pulla.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pulla.utils import is_this_a_git_dir
ImportError: No module named utils
```

The import works fine when using python3 as the executable.

This also works just fine(similar to python3) from command line in python2.

```
python/pulla git:(master) ✗ ± python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pulla
>>> import pulla.utils
>>> from pulla.utils import is_this_a_git_dir
>>> is_this_a_git_dir('.')
True
```

The code for this particular import is [here on github](https://github.com/shubhamchaudhary/pulla/blob/master/pulla/pulla.py#L5).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an implicit relative import. If your module has

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the top, that will force the import to be interpreted as an absolute import, so it's looking for the `utils` module on your `sys.path`, and not finding it. So you get an `ImportError`.

Hmm, I can't see that in your code. But anyway, if you still want the import to be a relative one, you can replace it with

```
from .utils import fly
```

This is an explicit package-relative import.

[Lots of information about absolute vs relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).